# Why Lempel-Ziv77 - "sliding window" algorithm uses a fixed length code for the buffer u?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, algorithms, coding-theory, compression

I am a final year ECE student from Greece, studying about Information Theory a question came up.

In the definition/description of LZ77 (Lempel-Ziv's algorithm), following is noted:

"If n > 1, encode the positive integer u ≤ w using a ***fixed-length*** code of length log w bits."

[LZ77_prntscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzSDJ.png)

My question is: ***Why using a fixed-length code and not a variable one? (such as a prefix free or any other uniquely decodable one?).***

Source of original lecture in English: [http://users.ece.northwestern.edu/~rberry/ECE428/Lectures/lec8_notes.pdf](http://users.ece.northwestern.edu/%7Erberry/ECE428/Lectures/lec8_notes.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you know $u\leq w$ using a fixed length code is usually much simpler. Just use the bit representation of $u$. And it makes no difference to the overall efficiency of the LZ77 scheme.

Comment: That was also my initial thought on the small analysis I've made (Google search till sun rises from Dawn) but seemed a bit simplistic.

Comment: remembering the scheme was designed in the 70s, simplicity would have been very important. In any case, if you wish, you could go to the original paper and see if this is mentioned or not, being at a university you should have access to IEEE database and find the paper.